# Call wcf service from plugin or workflow in dynamics crm

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a WCF service hosted on HostGator and I want to call that from workflow or plugin registered in plugin registration tool.
And I am working with Dynamics CRM online.

Is this possible?if yes then give me the solution or reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally using below link I get the answer.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-call-External-WCF-42c4490d

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible to call a WCF service from a sandboxed plugin/custom workflow activity. There are some restrictions thought (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)):

- Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
- Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
- **IP addresses cannot be used**. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
- Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.

Here's an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509030.aspx) from MSDN using WebClient, but it could be easier for instance if you add your service as a WebReference.

Comment: Hi Fedrico, I hosted my service in IIS Manager. So my URL is become like "192.168.1.126:1234/PAWebService.svc". so as you bold 3rd point of IP I have to write name instead of 192.168.1.126.write?

Comment: Hi Fedrico, when I am debug with plugin then at the stage of calling function of service with DNS name then each time  "Plugin Registration Tool has stop Working" is displayed and pluginregistration tool closed.what to do?

Comment: Yes, you can't use your IP, you have to use the DNS (for instance, if you host your service on Azure you have to use http://servicename.cloudapp.net/service.svc.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Plugin Registration Tool error, it could be related to several reasons. Maybe you can use the [Tracing Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx#loggingandtracing) as a workaround.