# Calling External WCF Service (using generated client) from CRM sandboxed plugin OnPremise is failing

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, sandbox, dynamics-crm-365

How to call HTTPS WCF web service in Plugin, plugin assembly is registered in sandbox mode. I am getting `System.Security.SecurityException` exception, Can somebody please provide the way to all https web service. My code is below :

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
myBinding.Name = “basicHttpBinding”;
if (EndPoint.ToLower().Contains(“https://”))
{
//Throwing exception here – System.Security.SecurityException exception,
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sendr, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)192;
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
}
else
{
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
}
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
myBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(EndPoint);
WebIALClient myClient = new WebIALClient(myBinding, endPointAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in on-premise version, you can register the plugin assembly in non-sandbox mode. ie `Isolation mode = none` to overcome such errors.

In case you wanted to use sandbox mode, try using `WebClient` class for invoking WCF service call. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162588)

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    byte[] responseBytes = client.DownloadData(webAddress);
                    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                    tracingService.Trace(response);

                    // For demonstration purposes, throw an exception so that the response
                    // is shown in the trace dialog of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM user interface.
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("WebClientPlugin completed successfully.");
                }
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun - But how can I pass the requestParameter here ? DownloadData accepts only uri address, it doesn't have any overload function which accepts the requestparam ?

Comment: Getting the same issue even after registering the plugin assembly in isolation mode "NONE" .

Comment: @user222419 this discussion maybe helpful - https://commdev.dynamics-int.com/crm/f/microsoft_dynamics_crm-26/163274/error-when-calling-external-webservice-from-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and also include: `using System.Web.Http.Cors;`

```
  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

  [Route("api/ConvertUpload/{env}/{id}")]

  public string Get(string env, string id)
  {

      return "hi";
  }
```

You may have to use WebClient as @Arun has mentioned.